# SQL Quieres specially on joins with certain conditions

Tags: sql

i have two tables :

```
empname, emid , depid , sal  

and 

depid ,depname
```

i want only depname and department wise average salary.

how can i do that?

Comment: Learn SQL and Aggregate functions

Comment: By joining the tables

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select depname, ave(sal) as AveSal
from employee
inner join department
on employee.depid = department.depid
group by depname
```